# Java scheduled threadpool executor internal queue

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I want to write a  program that runs every 30 minutes. I am using java scheduled threadpool executor to process the tasks that i submit to the executor.

I have been looking at what the official docs say https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

and i have run into a dilemma.

Lets say i have submitted 5 tasks to the queue and i have defined 10 threads in the thread pool.

1. Is there a likelyhood that one of the tasks shall be performed twice
2. Does the threadpool executor make sure that a task is removed when it has been     processed by one of the threads or must i remove the task myself once it has been processed.

Having the task removed is desirable since i wouldn't like old tasks to still be in the queue 30 minutes later.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I am running the code as provided by the tutorial i am reading , this is the ide link https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tRn5ZzZbtT

Comment: @孙兴斌 Who takes care of removing items that have been processed from the blockingqueue? The programmer or the threadpool executor?

Comment: @Gandalf the code from the link you posted is not using ScheduledExecutorService. For a fixed thread pool, each submitted task is executed exactly once.

Comment: @IllyesIstvan And what happens to the task after its executed? Removed from the queue by the executor?

Comment: @Gandalf in your example: yes
In a scheduled executor the scheduled tasks are executed at a given rate, so they will be executed multiple times.
Can you clarify your question? Are you looking to use a Scheduled thread pool?

Comment: As others said, `ThreadPoolExecutor` gurantees every task will be executed once. *I want to write a program that runs every 30 minutes.* Seems the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is unable to achieve it, are you looking for `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: @IllyesIstvan is this what the executor is made to do and in the docs, i cant seem to locate that part ascertaining that the processed task is actually removed.

Comment: @孙兴斌 Okay. is there documentation confirming that, 1. Its only executed once 2. Task is removed after its processed ... forgive my  skepticism, this sounds all too magical, i need some documented proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be executed only once, the executor will remove it automatically.

This is not explicitly documented, while the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) implys it:

> Executes the given task **sometime** in the future.

Answer (score 2):

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` creates a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` using a `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

From `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`:

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

When tasks are submitted for executions, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` will add them to this queue. Further, the worker threads will take tasks from this queue and execute them.

From `ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask()`:

```
private Runnable getTask() {
  // ...
        try {
            Runnable r = timed ?
                workQueue.poll(keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS) :
                workQueue.take();
            if (r != null)
                return r;
            timedOut = true;
        } catch (InterruptedException retry) {
            timedOut = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As per `BlockingQueue.take()` contract, taking an element from the queue implies removing it as well.

```
/**
 * Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary
 * until an element becomes available.
 *
 * @return the head of this queue
 * @throws InterruptedException if interrupted while waiting
 */
E take() throws InterruptedException;
```

Comment: Most discussions/Explanations does not specifically say whether the Blocking queue is compulsory or not. Or does it have a default queue anyway? With the documentations on callable futures, it is understood that their behavior includes a queue operation. Any comments?